# How to avoid NoSuchElementException in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

new to all of this, so I apologize if it's a stupid question.

here is all i am trying to do:

```
nxt_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/article/section/form/div[2]/button')
nxt_btn.click()
time.sleep(2)
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/article/section/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/fieldset/div/div/div[2]/div/input')
vote_check.click()
time.sleep(2)
nxt_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/article/section/form/div[2]/button')
nxt_btn.click()
driver.quit()
```

and it returns:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/main/article/section/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/fieldset/div/div/div[2]/div/input"}


(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
```

i've tried changing the wait time, choosing different elements, and checking to see if it is in an iframe, which if it is, i can't find it by just going up the path.

Comment: How about using `try: ... except NoSuchElementException: ...`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleep use Selenium explict waits

```
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "XPATH"))
```

Conditions you can use are:

1. visibility_of_element_located
2. text_to_be_present_in_element
3. element_to_be_clickable

Comment: Boiler plate code with no real explaination.

Comment: Thanks @debanjanB .I am learning  how to answer  surely from next answer  i won't  assume  and give real explanation.  On lighter note boiler plate code was quite harsh..lol